# replace parameter values from a file using python regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have file `load_file` which has contents like below (below is a trimmed version):
i want to replace the values for certain params dynamically.
for example, i want "BENCHMARK=EDA". the word 'BENCHMARK' may repeat mulitple times in the file.

```
# Official BENCHMARK values are
#       -SWBUILD
#       -VDA
#       -VDI
#       -DATABASE
#       -EDA
#
##############################################################################
BENCHMARK=VDI
LOAD=10
INCR_LOAD=10
NUM_RUNS=10
```

i tried to do the following:

```
  import re
  with open(load_file, 'r') as file:
     filedata = file.read()
  filedata=re.sub('BENCHMARK=*','BENCHMARK=EDA',filedata)
```

the above regex function is not working as i expected.
what am i missing in the regex method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected match is at the line start, and you need to match all text after `BENCHMARK=` to the end of the line.

Use

```
re.sub('(?m)^BENCHMARK=.*','BENCHMARK=EDA',filedata)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ac64OR).

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - the `(?m)` `re.DOTALL` inline modifier makes `^` match the start of a line
- `BENCHMARK=` - literal text
- `.*` - all the rest of the line.

You may also shorten the regex with a capturing group / backreference:

```
re.sub('(?m)^(BENCHMARK=).*', r'\1EDA',filedata)
```

where `\1` is the text captured with the `(BENCHMARK=)` group.